# Ajax inserts works with browsers but not with phonegap emulator (android)

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, emulation

I am developing an app with phonegap(cordova) version 3.2 and I am having problems with mysql insertion. The following codes works well in browsers (mobile or not) but, when I run the app with an android emulator or in a real device it doesn't work.

The scripts:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.js"></script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
         <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(e) {

                $("#formCadastro").submit(function(){
                var campoNome = new String(document.getElementById("txtNome").value);
                var campoEmail = new String(document.getElementById("txtEmail").value);
              var campoUsuario = new String(document.getElementById("txtUsuario").value);
                var campoSenha = new String(document.getElementById("txtSenha").value);
                var campoSenhaConf = new String(document.getElementById("txtSenhaConf").value);

                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "http://imagect.co.nf/cadastra.php",
                      crossDomain: true,
                      data: { nome: campoNome , email: campoEmail, usuario: campoUsuario, senha: campoSenha}
                        })
                    .done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                    window.location="index.html";
                    })
                    .fail(function(jqXHR, msg) {
                         alert( "Errooo:" + msg );
                         alert( "Errooo:" + jqXHR );
                         console.log("Erro chato:" + msg);
                         console.log(jqXHR + "  " + msg);
                    });



                });
            });
        </script>
```

The problem is that neither the fail function nor the success function happens. It seems that android ignores the ajax...
I have already tried using deviceready, pageinit, mobileinit etc. But nothing works well.
The manifest has the internet permission and the config.xml has the access origin = *.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks, sorry about my English.

Comment: Your English is great. Kudos to you. Some don't even bother trying.

Comment: Maybe it's stupid, but having two <script type="text/javascript"> is good ?

Comment: Thank you guys, but I think it's not the problem, because the page is working in the browser...

Comment: Have you tried `whitelisting` the specific URL instead of `*` wildcard? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: @JunM, but the * refers to any domain, doesn't it? So, if I specify the domain, it will be the same...Or not? I can be wrong..actually I haven't understood how all this domain stuff works in phonegap...Thank you!

Comment: In my case, I usually specify my url/domain. Though the documentations states that * means `Access to all domains`.

Comment: I think the problem is in the script...because it's weird that nothing happens when I submit the form, the page just refresh. If the error was in the server configurations it would return the fail function, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JunM I'll try, just one second...

Comment: No, the access origin was not the problem, in fact ,if I change its value to my domain address, the jquery wont load... But thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I noticed that the web browser log tell me:`Uncaught Reference: app is not defined`. It refers to the app in `app.initialize()`. Do you think it can be the problem?